# Acorn / JSX - walk nodes with particular type

Tags: javascript, acorn

I am parsing JSX (React component) to find all nodes that:

- belong to `JSXText` type
- Node has not empty parameter `text`

This is my first attempt to parse the component source file, with a test how to get `Literal` node.

```
const acorn = require("acorn")
const jsx = require("acorn-jsx")
const cf = require("acorn-class-fields")
const walk = require("acorn-walk")

let s = acorn.Parser.extend(cf).extend(jsx()).parse(cnt, {ecmaVersion: "latest", sourceType: "module"});
 walk.simple(s, {
Literal(node) {
                        console.log(`Literal: ${node.value}`)
                    }
})
```

**Question**

- I found nodes types [here](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md) but there aren't JSX node types - where could be found?
- How to filter nodes with not empty `text` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can extend `acorn-walk` to include the extra types.

This plugin works for me: https://github.com/sderosiaux/acorn-jsx-walk

At the time of writing, the following is how i would implement it:

```js
const acorn = require("acorn");
const jsx = require("acorn-jsx");
const walk = require("acorn-walk");
const { extend } = require('acorn-jsx-walk')

// setup
const parser = acorn.Parser.extend(jsx());
extend(walk.base);

// parse
const ast = parser.parse(cnt, { ecmaVersion: "latest", sourceType: 'module' });


// analys
walk.simple(ast, {
    JSXText(node) {
        console.log(node.expression)
    }
});
```

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to ask clarification questions. The answering part would benefit from a summary of what you linked, the single keyword is only barely elevating it above link-only level.